# Can an external USB VGA adapter be used as the primary monitor?

Tags: video, usb, display-adapter

I have an external USB video adapter (USB plug on one end, box with VGA connector on the other) – it's a Triton See2-UV150.

I was hoping it could be used as the only / primary adapter, but it does not seem to work that way. Just wanted to see if anyone knows if this device (or any other similar device) can be used as a display adapter for a machine to boot up?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I have Star Tech and Tritton USB adapters on a lot of the  systems in my work, I have mixed results getting them to work with windows 7 only had reliable success with  Win Xp. I don’t believe you can get them to work as the primary video source. Why would you want to? They wouldn’t load until the OS finished loading, because of the drivers and you would miss the boot sequence and logon. 
If you want to use a USB monitor as a primary monitor look for a USB solution that does not require the OS to load drivers.   No one of the adapters I have come up until after the logon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boxdog alluded to the answer.  If the BIOS cannot the access the device using a generic VGA interface, then that device cannot be the PC's (primary) display.  Maybe one day the typical BIOS will support a USB video adapter; I remember when PCs could not boot from a CD drive but now that is standard in every BIOS.